# Recursive javascript function returns out of order?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, github-api

So I have the following code that attempts to recursively find the files in a Github repo.

The folder structure looks like this

> master:
>
> master:gpapi/
>
> master:Documentation/
>
> master:Documentation/auth/
>
> master:Documentation/download/
>
> master:Documentation/search/

I'd expect the output to look like this:

> (master: call) -> master:Documentation/ is a tree!
>
> (master:Documentation/ call) -> master:Documentation/auth/ is a tree!
>
> (master:Documentation/auth/ call) -> master:Documentation/auth/ contents
>
> (master:Documentation/ call) -> master:Documentation/download/ is a tree!
>
> (master:Documentation/download/ call) -> master:Documentation/download/ contents
>
> (master:Documentation/ call) -> master:Documentation/search/ is a tree!
>
> (master:Documentation/search/ call) -> master:Documentation/search/ contents
>
> (master:Documentation/ call) -> master:Documentation/ contents
>
> (master: call) -> master:gpapi/ is a tree!
>
> (master:gpapi/ call) -> master:gpapi/ contents
>
> (master: call) -> master: contents

Instead, the output looked like this:

> (master: call) -> master:Documentation/ is a tree!
>
> (master: call) -> master:gpapi/ is a tree!
>
> (master: call) -> master: contents
>
> (master:Documentation/ call) -> master:Documentation/auth/ is a tree!
>
> (master:Documentation/ call) -> master:Documentation/download/ is a tree!
>
> (master:Documentation/ call) -> master:Documentation/search/ is a tree!
>
> (master:Documentation/ call) -> master:Documentation/ contents
>
> (master:gpapi/ call) -> master:gpapi/ contents
>
> (master:Documentation/download/ call) -> master:Documentation/download/ contents
>
> (master:Documentation/search/ call) -> master:Documentation/search/ contents
>
> (master:Documentation/auth/ call) -> master:Documentation/auth/ contents

How does the first function call evaluate the gpapi directory/tree before the most recent calls could evaluate Documentation's sub directories/trees? Is it an issue with how I am doing recursion or is it an issue with how console logging works?

Here is the code

```
//Package to connect to GitHub's GraphQL API
var GithubGraphQLApi = require('node-github-graphql') 

//Package to edit SQL db
var sql = require('mysql'); 

//Connect to GitHub API
var github = new GithubGraphQLApi({
  token: process.env.GITHUB_API_TOKEN,
  debug: true
})

//Call the recursive function
populatefiles("googleplay-api", "master:");

//Find all the files in a repo for a given path
function populatefiles(repo_name, path){
    //Query the GitHub API for all files in repo <repo_name>
    //found at <path>
    github.query(`
        {
            viewer {
                repository(name: "` + repo_name +`") {
                    object(expression: "` + path +`") {
                        ... on Tree{
                            entries{
                                name
                                type
                                mode
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        `, null, (res, err) => {

        //The array of files returned by Github
        var entries  = res.data.viewer.repository.object.entries

        for (var e in entries){
            var entry = entries[e];

            //If the entry is a directory("tree") 
            if(entry.type === "tree"){

                //update the path and log it
                var newpath = path + entry.name + "/";
                console.log(newpath + " is a tree!");

                //call the function with the new path
                populatefiles(repo_name, newpath);
            }
        }
        //log all entries found at <path>
        console.log(path + " contents");
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2))
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're dealing with promises, and promises are asynchronous. To get them to work synchronously, you have to "chain" them together with a `.then()` or something like that.

I haven't tested this code, but this is the general idea. You'll want to assign the return value of `github.query()`, which will be the promise. Then you can use a `.then()`. In the `for` loop, things get a little interesting.

The way I'm doing it here (putting all the promises into an array and then calling a `Promise.all`, you can't be sure about the order of each iteration of the `for` loop. If you need to be sure about the order, you'd need to chain those as well. I've inserted sample code for that in comments. (see the `pr2` lines).

```
//Call the recursive function
populatefiles("googleplay-api", "master:")
    .then(x => console.log('all done'));
.catch(e => console.log('error!', e));

//Find all the files in a repo for a given path
function populatefiles(repo_name, path) {
    //Query the GitHub API for all files in repo <repo_name>
    //found at <path>
    var pr = github.query(`
        {
            viewer {
                repository(name: "` + repo_name + `") {
                    object(expression: "` + path + `") {
                        ... on Tree{
                            entries{
                                name
                                type
                                mode
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        `);

    pr = pr.then(res => {

        //The array of files returned by Github
        var entries = res.data.viewer.repository.object.entries
        var prarr = [];
        // var pr2 = Promise.resolve(); // create a resolved promise to start the chain, if you're worried about order of the for loop.
        for (var e in entries) {
            var entry = entries[e];

            //If the entry is a directory("tree") 
            if (entry.type === "tree") {

                //update the path and log it
                var newpath = path + entry.name + "/";
                console.log(newpath + " is a tree!");

                //call the function with the new path
                prarr.push(populatefiles(repo_name, newpath));
                // pr2 = pr2.then(populatefiles(repo_name, newpath)); // if you're worried about order of the loop
            }
        }
        //log all entries found at <path>
        console.log(path + " contents");
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2))
        return Promise.all(prarr);
        //return pr2; // if you're worried about the order of the loop
    });

    return pr;
}
```

*Edit: One other thing I forgot to mention: with promises, you always want to have at least one `.catch()` at the end of the chain, in case there is an error. Node gets really grumpy if you don't and will give you a warning message about unhandled promises.